# Using a global TList<real>

Tags: delphi, generics

I wanted to primarily ask whether using TList would be more appropriate than changing the length of a dynamic array each time a new item is to be appended. Like so:

```
SetLength(DynamicArray, Length(DynamicArray)+1);
DynamicArray[length(DynamicArray)] := NewElement;
```

---

Assuming that it is more approrpiate.. I was wondering if something like this would work if I wanted to make a global dynamic array, accessible by all functions in the unit.

```
type
   Tdata = Record
     y: TList<real>;
     x: TList<integer>;
End;

var
  data: Tdata;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  data.y  := TList<real>.Create;
  data.y.add(1.2);
  data.y.add(2.3);
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject); // Some button click event
begin
  Memo1.lines.add(data.y.count); // Should output 2
end;
```

I'm confused as to where I need to create the TList, and why we need to create it in the first place, unlike a normal array. Do I need to create the TList again in the event function, and when would I free it? I am following [this example,](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/Generics_Collections_TList_(Delphi)) but i'm still confused how this would work with functions?
Thanks,
Jonathon

Comment: Create it before you first use it. Destroy after you last use it.

Comment: FWIW, In Delphi use Double or Single. Real is a legacy type, and depending on settings, it can even be different. Real usually maps to Double but rather use that type directly, to be sure.

Comment: Please specify your Delphi version.

Comment: Hi, i'm using Delphi 10.2.2

Comment: `TList<T>` uses a dynamic array internally, it just manages the array growth more efficiently. `TList` is a class, so it needs to be created. Since you have a single global instance, I would suggest creating it in the unit's `initialization` and freeing it in the unit's `finalization`.

Comment: Since Delphi XE7 you can add to a dynamic array with `DynamicArray := DynamicArray + [NewElement]`

Comment: @Brian Thanks, this seems to be easier to do than changing all my arrays into TLists. Do you know whether this is the same efficiency as appending dynamic arrays by one, or manages array growth more efficiently?

Comment: No, extending arrays by one element at a time is less efficient in terms of runtime performance and probably memory address space fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm confused as to where I need to create the TList, and why we need to create it in the first place, unlike a normal array.

A [TList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList) is an object that must be instantiated by a call to `Create`.
Like any object that is allocated on the heap, it must be created before use.

When you don't need it anymore, it must be deallocated by a call to `Free`. Note that a `TList` has other characteristics than an array. It has methods, properties, etc, to handle sorting, comparisons, insertion and things like that.

---

A "normal" array can be either a static array or a dynamic array.

- A [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) is a managed type, where the lifetime is automatically handled by the use of a reference count. It is allocated to the heap by a call to `SetLength`, or by a concatenation with another array or value.
- A [static array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Static_Arrays) is automatically stack allocated whenever it is within scope, and thus needs no explicit creation.

---

> Do I need to create the TList again in the event function, and when would I free it?

In your example, the variable `data` is a global. Once the `x` or `y` fields have been allocated, they are alive until they are destroyed. So, no you don't have to create them again.

As @Remy says, if you want to use the `data` variable throughout the unit, it can be initialized and finalized in the initialization and finalization part of the unit.

---

> I wanted to primarily ask whether using TList would be more appropriate than changing the length of a dynamic array each time a new item is to be appended.

Like mentioned above, a `TList<T>` is an object with methods for sorting etc.
If you don't need those extra functions, a dynamic array is ok.

If you are thinking about performance, use a profiler first to find if you actually will gain anything by optimizing code. Adding items one by one on a dynamic array may be slower than using a TList. A TList will grow its internal array in larger chunks to avoid too much heap reallocations.

Comment: If, for example, I need the array throughout the duration of the program, do I have to free it before terminating the program? Does it make a difference if I do not free it?

Comment: If you mean the `TList` object, it is better to free it, yes. If you don't, the OS will take care of it, but you should always clean up to make debugging easier.